# i have a problem in tensorflow when i exe the neuralintents library

Tags: python, tensorflow

i have install tensorflow with the command:

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

and it gives me this problem:

```
  File "c:\Users\User\OneDrive\Bureau\Alexa\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from neuralintents import GenericAssistant
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\neuralintents\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from neuralintents.main import GenericAssistant
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\neuralintents\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114   
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
```

I want to make voice assistant and I never use tensorflow:

```
import sys
import threading
import tkinter as tk

import speech_recognition
import pyttsx3 as tts
from neuralintents import GenericAssistant

class Assistant:
    def __init__(self):
        self.recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
        self.speaker = tts.init()
        self.speaker.setProperty("rate", 150)

        self.assistant = GenericAssistant("intents.json", intent_methods={"file": self.create_file})
        threading.Thread(target=self.run_assitnat).start()

    def create_file(self):
        with open("somefile.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("Hellow world")

    def run_assistant(self):
        while True:
            try:
                with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
                    self.recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.2)
                    audio = self.recognizer.listen(mic)
                    
                    text = self.recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                    text = text.lower()

                    if "hey jake" in text:
                        audio = self.recognizer.listen(mic)
                        text = self.recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                        text = text.lower()
                        if text == "stop":
                            self.speaker.say("Bye")
                            self.speaker.runAndWait()
                            self.speaker.stop()
                            sys.exit()

                        else:
                            if text is not None:
                                response = self.assistant.request(text)
                                if response is not None:
                                    self.speaker.say(response)
                                    self.speaker.runAndWait()
                                
            except:continue
Assistant()
```

Comment: The traceback appears to be incomplete. The last few lines are important; please [edit] to include them.

Answer (score 0):

You are installing `TF 1.x` for `Python 3.11`. `Tensorflow 1.x` is only supported with `Python version<=3.7`. Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu).

You can install the latest tensorflow version as per installed python version using

```
!pip install tensorflow
```

or can downgrade the [python](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package_location) version `3.7` or below to install `Tensorflow 1.x`